# Bootstrap 3 grid, Align columns in same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, height

As you can see in the image, I am using the bootstrap 3 grid system, and these are 2 columns, in the same row, but they aren't aligned. I want them to be clear to the user that they are at the same level, and as of right now, it looks confusing. Can someone help me out?

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6LOx.jpg

Bootstrap code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 ">
         <h3>Total</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 ">
         <h3>$1,618.20</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One of your h3 headers isnt closed properly.  Other than that it works for me. Cant replicate the problem

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine for me, its alignment is correct only

Actually the `class` like `row`, `col` does not contain `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom`

Inside the `<div class="col-sm-6 ">` you were using `<h3>` for assigning values, or you can use any other tags also. In that assigning tag use the `style="margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;"`
This may solve your problem

Like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 ">
         <h3 style="margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">Total</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 ">
         <h3 style="margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">$1,618.20</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can use this class

```
h3 {
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Hope this may useful